# Making Windows to go usb on UBUNTU

Tags: ubuntu, bootable-media

How can i make "windows to go" usb using operating system ubuntu or other linux distros. I have iso image of windows 10 and 32gb usb stick and running ubuntu, and i want to make windows to go 32gb stick

Comment: So what step are you stuck on exactly?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/889342/692175

Answer (score -1):

You can try running Rufus in Wine:

1. Install a Rufus .exe file at https://rufus.ie
   You can get the installer or portable but in this answer, I'm going to use portable.
2. Open a terminal and do the following:

```
sudo apt install wine
```

This will install WINE and take a while.

3. Cd to your rufus .exe file:

```
cd <path/to/rufus-X.X.exe>
```

Where the X replaces your version no.

4. Run Rufus:

```
wine <name of rufus .exe file>
```

For e.g:

```
sudo wine rufus-3.5p.exe
```

5. Then go here to work out how to do it with Rufus:
   https://beebom.com/how-create-windows-to-go-usb/
   Look for the part where it says: "Create Windows To Go USB Using Rufus"

Hope this helps!

-GalaxCode

Comment: Rufus installed via wine cannot detect drives